# Iterate two collection at same time

Tags: ruby, loops

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5  ]
```

What I want is to iterate these two collection at same time and do something with iterator, the pseudo code would be like:

```
for i in a
for j in b
collect i * j
```

when one collection runs out of element, the loop stops.

the result will be `[4, 10]`

What I have is this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5  ]

a.zip(b).reject { |c| c.any? { |d| d.nil? } }.map { |e| e.reduce(&:*) }
```

Any better solution? Thanks!

And The perfect solution I am looking for is to match the intent of my pseudo code.

Comment: If your code is working and you just want to improve it, the question becomes off-topic for [so] and becomes on-topic for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
a, b = b, a if b.length < a.length

a.zip(b).map { |ia, ib| ia * ib }
# => [4, 10]
```

The first line makes sure that array `a` has at most the same number of elements as array `b`. This is because `zip` creates an array of arrays of the length of the called array. Having `a` as the shortest array makes sure that there would be no `nil`s.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it:

```
[a.length, b.length].min.times.map {|i| a[i]*b[i] }
```

The idea is that you take the shorter of the two array lengths, `[a.length, b.length].min`, and you iterate that many times over an integer, `i`, which you use as an index into the arrays.